# On generalised inverse

Tags: matrices, inverse

Let $A$ be a positive matrix, may not be invertible. I define its generalised inverse as 
\begin{equation}
A^- = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac{1}{n} I + A\right)^{-1}.
\end{equation}
Lets consider a strictly positive matrix $B$ (which by definition, is invertible). Is it true that
\begin{equation}
(BAB)^- = B^{-1}A^- B^{-1}.
\end{equation}
Advanced thanks for any helps and suggestions.

Comment: @JohnMa Exactly. Thanks for mentioning. Corrected :)

Comment: It seems that the limit does not exist if $A$ is only nonnegative. On the other hand, if $A$ is positive, it seems that $A^-$ is just the inverse of $A$.

Comment: If $A$ is non-negative definite, Then both $A$ and $\frac{1}{n}I+A$ are diagonalised by same unitary. Eigen values will be $\lambda_1+\frac{1}{n}, \cdots, \lambda_k+\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}, \cdots, \frac{1}{n}$. For this the limit exists, and is precisely $\lambda_i,~i=1,\cdots, k$ and zeros. If we look it in this way, the limit exists obviously, isn't it?

Comment: Let say if $A$ is the zero matrix, then the limit does not exist.

Comment: You are right. But my concern is on the non null space. Is there a nice way to modify the above definition (if necessary) so that it can mimic standard inverse as much as possible in its support?

Comment: Can you just define it to be the matrix with eigenvalues $1/\lambda_1, \cdots, 1/\lambda_k, 0,0,\cdots, 0$ (with the same diagonalization)

Comment: The inverse exists on the subspace orthogonal to the null space of $A$